# Container registry behind reverse proxy Nginx Proxy Manager slow on docker push

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, gitea

In the past I tried setting up Jfrog Artifactory OSS and was able to get it through my reverse proxy exposed outside my home network, and I was able to push to it VIA my computer local CLI and through Drone CI but it took an abnormal amount of time (roughly 5 min) to push to my own registry when pushing to DockerHub or Gitlab took a matter of seconds.

My container is really small (think MBs) and I never have any issues with pushing it to any other remote registry. I always thought it might have been the registry and the fact it was running on an old machine until now.

I recently discovered my git solution Gitea has a registry built in, so I did the same, I got everything set up and mapped and once again it took an abnormal amount of time (roughly 5 min) to push to my own registry (this time backed by Gitea).

This leads me to think my issues is Nginx Proxy Manager related. I found some documenation online but it was really general and vague, I have the current proxy config below and it still has the issue. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I also included a few other posts related to this issue.

```
server {
  set $forward_scheme http;
  set $server         "192.168.X.XX";
  set $port           3000;

  listen 8080;
#listen [::]:8080;

listen 4443 ssl http2;
#listen [::]:4443;


  server_name my.domain.com;

  # Let's Encrypt SSL
  include conf.d/include/letsencrypt-acme-challenge.conf;
  include conf.d/include/ssl-ciphers.conf;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-47/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-47/privkey.pem;

  # Force SSL
  include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf;

  access_log /data/logs/proxy-host-10_access.log proxy;
  error_log /data/logs/proxy-host-10_error.log warn;
  
  #Additional fields I added ontop of the default Nginx Proxy Manager config
  proxy_buffering off; proxy_ignore_headers "X-Accel-Buffering";
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  location / {
    # Proxy!
    include conf.d/include/proxy.conf;
  }
  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
}
```

I also checked the live logs for Gitea and I see the requests coming real time and processed really fast, but there is always a significant delay before it receives the next request which makes me think the Nginx Proxy Manager is not correctly forwarding the requests or there is some setting that I missed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Some of the settings I got to try were from the below sources
[Another registry](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/970#issuecomment-139414612)

[Another stack overflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68998110/8372325)